# First chance FileNotFoundException when calling IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage

Somewhere in my code, I have this line:

```
return _store.OpenFile(path, fileMode);
```

With `fileMode` being sometimes `FileMode.Create` and sometimes `FileMode.Open`.
Everything works well, I always get a valid stream and if necessary, the file is correctly created.

But, I've just discovered in my VS output that I have the following message every time I call the method where the above line is:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

I get this error when the file is created and I also get this error when the file is overwritten (and obviously exists).

I'm just curious about these errors since everything works perfectly.

Thanks,

**EDIT:** Same thing with `new IsolatedStorageFileStream(...)`. Everything works fine but I still get the "first chance exception" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

It's just how VS debugger works: for every exception caught by a {{catch}} block, a "first chance exception" message appears in the VS output.
So here, we can guess that, internally, the {{OpenFile}} method uses a try/catch block to check if the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs;

if (!isf.FileExists(_filename))
    isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(_filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create, isf);
else
    isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(_filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open, isf);


var writer = XmlWriter.Create(isfs);
xml.Save(writer);

writer.Close();
isfs.Close();
isfs.Dispose();
isf.Dispose();
```

Comment: Nope. Same thing. Creating a new `IsolatedStorageFileStream` is equivalent to calling `OpenFile` (as said in the MSDN). I always get the error message when first creating the file but then, I don't get them when I re-open them.